# jquery sortable move duplicates to bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a data sortable list:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="1" data-name="NAME1">NAME1 + INFO1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="3" data-name="NAME4">NAME4 + INFO4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="9" data-name="NAME1">NAME1 + INFO1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="8" data-name="NAME6">NAME6 + INFO6</li>
</ul>

$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

How could I add the script to move duplicates (or more times) of data-name to bottom of the list?

So, if currently the list is NAME1, NAME4, NAME1, NAME6 then with duplicates moved to bottom the list would be NAME1, NAME4, NAME6, NAME1.

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this via PHP arrays.

I create three different arrays (name not listed at all; name listed once; name listed more times) and then echo them in suitable order.